# Convert a JavaScript file back to it's TypeScript code using it's declaration and sourcemap file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, source-maps, typescript-declarations

I had a file, `module.ts` written in TypeScript and compiled it to JavaScript for production deployment. What was I left with were the following files;

1. module.js (the TypeScript code compiled into JavaScript)
2. module.d.ts (the declaration file)
3. module.js.map (the source file)

Now I want to revert the `module.js` back to `module.ts` file using all these 3 files because I don't have that `.ts` file anymore.

I tried loading `module.js` inside the browser, hoping it should load it's `.ts` file into the Developer Tools, using the Sourcemap, but it doesn't. I believe I am missing the point here of having a Sourcemap after all.

Comment: Source maps generally contain just the mapping from the js to the ts files (ie what span in js maps to what span in ts), they generally just contains references to the source code. Source maps cam include the source code in the file but this is not enabled in ts (might be behind a flag, not sure). Open the file in a text editor, it the file does not contain recoganizable ts code, then the ts is lost forever, the declration file does not contain enough info to rebuild ts code

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, what if the file contains recognizable ts code ?

Comment: @AndreiGătej if the source map file contains recognizable ts code you can just take it from there. Source maps are json files, you can write a small utility to get at the property containing the source code. Or you can load the files into a debugger that recognizes source maps